# YARVInstructionSequence/SimpleDataFormat to Source conversion

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

A proc can be converted in to Ruby virtual machine sequences in `YARVInstructionSequence/SimpleDataFormat` as follows:

```
RubyVM::InstructionSequence.of(->x{x + 1}).to_a
# => ["YARVInstructionSequence/SimpleDataFormat", 2, 0, 1,
  {:arg_size=>1, :local_size=>2, :stack_max=>2},
  "block in irb_binding", "(irb)", nil, 2,
  :block, [:x], [1, [], 0, 0, -1, -1, 3],
  [
    [:redo, nil, :label_0, :label_9, :label_0, 0],
    [:next, nil, :label_0, :label_9, :label_9, 0]
  ],
  [
    :label_0, 2, [:trace, 256], [:trace, 1], [:getlocal_OP__WC__0, 2],
    [:putobject_OP_INT2FIX_O_1_C_],
    [:opt_plus, {:mid=>:+, :flag=>256, :orig_argc=>1, :blockptr=>nil}], :label_9,
    [:trace, 512], [:leave]
  ]
]
```

Is there a way to convert this format back to reconstruct the source expression in string like `"->x{x+1}"` or something close to it?

The format is explained in [RDoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/RubyVM/InstructionSequence.html#method-i-to_a) as follows:

[image: doc1]
[image: doc2]
[image: doc3]
[image: doc4]

Comment: Think about it. In the same way that you can never decompile C/C++ code to the original, you can't decompile Ruby code. Too much data is lost in translation.

Comment: I don't know much about compilation. What information is lost?

Comment: Syntax and formatting information. Compilation will usually only contain enough information to maintain the semantics of the original code, not the way it was written, especially if there are multiple ways to write the code. Take a look at some questions on C/C++ decompilation, and then you'll see why.

Comment: I know. That is why I asked for "something close". I do not mind if `def foo; :bar end` becomes `def foo\n:bar\nend` or if `foo ? bar : baz` becomes `if foo then bar; else baz end`.

Comment: @sawa, do you still get any solution about this?